# extracting properties from NSArray of objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, nsarray

Is there any of way (other than looping) of extracting a particular property of all objects in an array. So say there in an array of people. I want to extract all their first names into an array.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Key Value coding will help you with that:

```
NSArray *result = [people valueForKey:@"firstname"];
```

Comment: Big +1 to JustSid.
Works great.
Note: `people` must be an NSArray to be true. If `people` is a NSSet the result will be a NSSet

Comment: How to achieve the same in swift ?

Answer (score -1):

I got answer for my question.
This is how we can achieve the same in swift.

```
let arraytWithProperties = arrayWithObjects.map{ $0.propertyName }
```