# extracting properties from NSArray of NSArray of NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, key-value-coding, nsorderedset

This question is similar to [extracting properties from NSArray of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312032/extracting-properties-from-nsarray-of-objects), but for deeper extraction.

For the sake of simplicity, the *objects* I am referring to in the below examples are NSStrings.

I have two cases I want to solve.

### NSArray of NSArray of NSDictionary with objects

Preferably with Key-Value-coding, from the following structure, I'd like to extract all the "title" into a single enumerable list:

```
NSArray *list1 = @[
    @[
        @{@"title":@"A", @"description":...},
        @{@"title":@"B", @"description":...},
    ],
    @[
        @{@"title":@"C", @"description":...},
        @{@"title":@"D", @"description":...},
    ],
];
```

Desired result would be for example:

```
@[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D"]
```

### NSArray of NSDictionary with NSArray of objects

Preferably with Key-Value-coding, from the following structure, I'd like to extract the lists of "titles" into a single enumerable list:

```
NSArray *list2 = @[
    @{
        @"titles":@[
            @"A",
            @"B",
        ],
        @"descriptions":...,
    },
    @{
        @"titles":@[
            @"C",
            @"D",
        ],
        @"descriptions":...,
    },
];
```

Desired result would be for example:

```
@[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D"]
```

### Notes

- My real cases involve `NSOrderedSet` of `NSOrderedSet` of objects for first list and `NSOrderedSet` of `NSDictionary` with `NSOrderedSet` of objects for second list, but that shouldn't affect the answers I think.
- I wrote I would prefer to use key-value-coding, but that is not a must. I just want to avoid, if possible, writing `for (... in ...)` or `enumateObjectWithBlock:`.
- Again that shouldn't matter, but objects are NSManagedObject from fetch requests. So I know I could just optimise the fetch requests directly, but I still want to know if there are nice alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

KVC can indeed do your bidding in this case, via a [Collection Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html) called [`@unionOfArrays`](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-178611). One effect of this operator is to flatten arrays, so your first example is very simple.

```
[list1 valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.title"]
```

The second is quite similar, but you have to do it in the reverse order. First extract all the `titles` arrays, then flatten them.

```
[list2 valueForKeyPath:@"titles.@unionOfArrays.self"]
```

The `self` is necessary -- although it seems redundant -- because, per the doc linked above

> All the collection operators, with the exception of `@count`, require a key path to the right of the collection operator.

For `NSOrderedSet`, it would seem that you could use its `array` property in the key path to convert the inner collections before operating on them, but for some reason this produces errors. I found this interesting tidbit, however, posted [on GitHub by Nicolas Bouilleaud](https://gist.github.com/n-b/4134555):

```
// Convert each OrderedSet to an Array to mute the error.
NSLog(@"union : %@",[data valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfArrays.values.@array"]);
```

and this weird `@array` *operator* works on your `NSOrderedSet` sample input:

```
NSOrderedSet *list1 = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects:[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:@[ @{@"title":@"A"}, @{@"title":@"B"} ]], [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:@[ @{@"title":@"C"}, @{@"title":@"D"} ]], nil];

// Note also converting outer set to array first    
NSLog(@"%@", [list1.array valueForKeyPath:@"@unionOfArrays.title.@array"]);

NSOrderedSet *list2 = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:@[ @{ @"titles":[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects: @"A", @"B", nil] }, @{ @"titles":[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects: @"C", @"D", nil] } ]];

// Note also converting outer set to array first
NSLog(@"%@", [list2.array valueForKeyPath:@"titles.@unionOfArrays.self.@array"]);
```

but *I have no idea why*. I can't figure out where this comes from or what it's doing (why it's at the end, in particular).

Comment: Nice. Any idea to support NSOrderedSet?

Comment: If you need to eliminate duplicates in the result, substitute `@distinctUnionOfArrays`. Either one works on `NSArray` or `NSSet`.

Comment: For an `NSOrderedSet` as the original outer container, I think you'll have to convert to array first.

Comment: For "outer container", yes, a simple conversion will be enough.
But for "inner container" being an NSOrderedSet, I tried my best but couldn't find a KVC compliant syntax. See my answer.

Comment: I've updated with some more info I found about the inner ordered sets, @Cœur.

Comment: Whoah! Congratulations at finding an undocumented operator `@array` that solves my question. I wonder if Apple allows to use it.

Comment: I will update if I find a more solid explanation; it's true that it may break unexpectedly, but then again, it may not. I suppose `@array` would make a good SO question in itself...

Comment: Ah ah ah, look at that as well:
`[list1.set valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfSets.title.@set"]`, `[list2.set valueForKeyPath:@"titles.@distinctUnionOfSets.self.@set"]`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Josh for the answer regarding NSArray. When I asked my question, I described it using NSArray because it was easier to write with the modern `@[]` syntax. I couldn't imagine that the most appropriate answer for NSArray would be **incompatible** with my real case of `NSOrderedSet`.

So, my real case is closer to that:

```
NSOrderedSet *list1 = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects:[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:@[ @{@"title":@"A"}, @{@"title":@"B"} ]], [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:@[ @{@"title":@"C"}, @{@"title":@"D"} ]], nil];
NSOrderedSet *list2 = [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:@[ @{ @"titles":[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects: @"A", @"B", nil] }, @{ @"titles":[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithObjects: @"C", @"D", nil] } ]];
```

And the only solutions for NSOrderedSet I could find are sadly using a loop:

```
NSMutableOrderedSet *listA = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSet];
for (NSOrderedSet *set in [list1 valueForKey:@"title"]) {
    [listA unionOrderedSet:set];
}

NSMutableOrderedSet *listB = [NSMutableOrderedSet orderedSet];
for (NSDictionary *object in list2) {
    [listB unionOrderedSet:object[@"titles"]];
}
```

[edit: apparently Josh found an undocumented `@array` operator to solve the issue. Contratz!]